# Using my own gensalt() - Is it safe enough?

Tags: python, security, bcrypt

Since the mechanism of bcrypt is:

```
>>> myhash = bcrypt.hashpw('testpassword', bcrypt.gensalt(12))
>>> myhash    
'$2a$12$K1hnCm5z74QtXaynv4.S8.i1FK9xjRr7JSPCRCyB9zpv8xZznZGFi'
>>> bcrypt.hashpw('testpassword', myhash)
'$2a$12$K1hnCm5z74QtXaynv4.S8.i1FK9xjRr7JSPCRCyB9zpv8xZznZGFi'
```

I want to use it for auth. The problem is that I want to make it from the client, so I need the *salt* part in the client.

I thought, if I use my own `gensalt(username)` — which generates a salt from a user name — it could be good for the client to always use the same salt, different from other users.

**Is that a good approximation to bcrypt and for my project, or am I breaking the security in bcrypt mechanism?**

I’m thinking that if someone wants to decrypt the password, it can’t be possible using rainbow tables because (s)he must use one for each user. I’m not experienced enough in security issues to know if that would be good. Maybe the `hashpw` is fast enough to do brute force on a PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is:  **No**, what you are describing isn't secure at all.

First of all,  bcrypt is not an encryption function and there for its results of this function cannot be "decrypted".  bcrypt is a message digest function built using blowfish. Hashes produced by a message digest function are cracked.

It is very problematic for a client to authenticate using a message digest function.  Microsoft's NTLM uses a message digest function for authentication and it has been [broken many times](http://www.hexale.org/advisories/OCHOA-2010-0209.txt).  I think that this approach to authentication is flawed and should be avoided.

The reason why message digest functions are used is as a defense in depth measure in security in layers.  If an attacker is able to find a sql injection vulnerability you want to force them to spend resources to break the hash before they can login.  If i can pull the hash out of the database,  and use this to login,  then your system is totally worthless.   **Replay attacks** are a huge concern when a client authenticates with a hash.  If I can sniff the network and replay the login sequence,  then this system is totally worthless.

Generate a random salt, `bcrypt.gensalt(12)` is probably fine.  Store the hash and the salt in your database.  You must authenticate using a secure transport layer.  Make sure you read [owasp a9](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection).

Comment: I'm thinking about using wss (secure websockets) like a protocol in order to send all data ) . Do you think that's safe?

Comment: @A.Quiroga  use SSL/TLS and send the password in plantext.  calculate and compare the hash on the server.  Every application does this,  and this is the right way of doing it.